# How to detect syntax error in unity shader scripting

Tags: unity, shaders

[image]

Hi. I'm following shader scripting tutorial and I often make syntax mistakes. 
like other languages, can you have visual studio automatically underline with red color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [Shader Unity Support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MarcinODev.ShaderUnitySupport)?

also you need to install parts of Visual Studio C/C++ for this to work

[image]